# dual-boot (ElCapitan and Mojave) on a Mac Pro 5,1?

Tags: mojave, dual-boot

I have a 2012 Mac Pro 5,1, running El Capitan.  I wish to make it a dual-boot system, El Capitan and Mojave.  I understand that I must install High Sierra preliminary to Mojave, and must install a "metal"-capable graphics card (I've purchased, but not yet installed, a Sapphire PULSE Radeon RX 580).

I have my El Capitan system on a 240GB SSD; user directories are on a separate HDD.  I've created a 2nd partition on the SSD and done a clean install of High Sierra there.   The installer made it an APFS volume, so when I am booted into El Capitan, I cannot select High Sierra as my Startup Disk (El Capitan cannot "see" the APFS volume in System Prefs).  I can select High Sierra using the Startup Manager (<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> during startup). But my understanding is that once I install the new GPU (prior to upgrading to Mojave) that the Startup Manager will not work (no boot screen)  Thus, once I boot into El Capitan, there is no way to then boot into High Sierra.

Is it possible to resolve this?  I've read that it's possible to install High Sierra on an HFS+ partition, but not Mojave.  Perhaps I can live with High Sierra and Mojave as my two boot options instead, if I can get my older apps to work on High Sierra?  But even then, without a boot screen, it's impossible to get to recovery disks etc (what happens if the boot drive fails?).  Is the only option to obtain a GPU that supports the boot screen?  Apparently macvidcards.com sell such cards and could modify mine, but they appear very sketchy, from searches I've done.

EDIT: This post may partially be a wild-goose chase - my apologies. I've determined I *can* probably run all my apps under High Sierra (and possibly under Mojave) - I was mistaken/confused originally - so it's looking like I may not need to boot ElCap anymore.  But there may be other users who *do* need to, so I still think it's a discussion worth having.   However, the boot-screen issue remains - in particular being able to boot from recovery partitions or external media.

Comment: Suggestion: put Mojave on a separate drive, then swap to whichever you wish to boot to. I'm not sure how you'll fly blind with a non-flashed GPU to try swap over otherwise. I have one Mac Pro with a non-flashed card but if it fails I have flashed ones I can swap in for troubleshooting.

Comment: I still don't see how I'd swap to the Mojave drive, from ElCapitan, without a boot screen - since the Mojave APFS volume can't be seen when logged into ElCap.  IOW, I don't see how putting Mojave on a separate drive helps me; what am I missing ?

Comment: @RustyShackleford Use Startup Disk preferences. Select the disk with macOS Mojave and enter the password to decrypt the disk if FileVault was on. Then select restart to startup on macOS Mojave.

Comment: @Todd The problem is that if I'm in ElCapitan, that SystemPrefs->StartupDisk cannot "see" Mojave (it can't even see HighSierra now).     Are you guys trying to tell me that if I put HighSierra/Mojave on a separate drive (instead of on a separate partition as it is now), that somehow I'll be able to select it as StartupDisk ?

Comment: @RustyShackleford yes that might work too but since updating to macOS High Sierra updates firmware necessary for Mojave, OS X El Capitan might still not see Mojave in System Preferences and the Mac might not boot from it in Startup Manager.

Comment: I'm fairly sure ElCap won't be able to see Mojave from what I've read - because apparently it can't see HighSierra because it's on APFS, and Mojave is too.  So it'd take an update to ElCap to fix that.   Could be wrong I guess.

Comment: Sometimes the throwing hardware at the problem is the best solution - can you add a second video card?  One that's supported under El Capitan and the other for Mojave/Catalina?  I've seen this other people's setups, but not for your purposes.

Comment: Well I could just keep the card that's in there now (I haven't put the "metal-capable" card in yet).   I believe I have room for both.   It's a lot of power - assuming I could even power both simultaneously (and the Radeon uses both 6-pin jacks on the motherboard).  And I'll still have to switch the monitor cable (or buy some kind of DVI switch).   But the main issue is being able to get to the boot screen if I need it - and I can temporarily power up the old card for that.

Comment: See my EDIT above.

Comment: Rusty - my idea was literally to take one drive out & put another drive in, something which takes a whole 10 seconds on a Mac Pro… but I'd guess David's rEFInd suggestion would be easier ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - Wow, you got me, had no clue that's what you meant.   So that begs the musical question, if the disk that the machine WAS booting from disappears, what happens - I guess it looks for any other bootable drive.  So I probably have to remove some old OSX installation on my big user-directory disk, 'cause it might go to that one instead of the newly-inserted one that you intended it to boot from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to install [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Boot Manager. This is free software which can be configured many different ways. Below is a suggested configuration.

By default, rEFInd installs in the EFI partition. You can then configure rEFInd to either boot El Capitan or Mojave. The default operating system to boot can be set directly from the operating system. There is simple AppleScript application you can [download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/startup-for-refind/) which will do this. As example of the application is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Looks intriguing, gonna require a little digging to figure it all out, so not upvoting yet.   Thanks

Comment: With this, I still need to be booted up on one OS to change to another, right ?  So it doesn't really get around the boot-screen issue ?

Comment: The idea is to use the AppleScript application instead of the Startup pane of System Preferences to choose the default operating system to boot. You would have to install the  AppleScript application in both operating systems. The application reads the choices from a rEFInd configuration file stored in the EFI partition. Any change in choices is written back to this file. When you boot/reboot your Mac, rEFInd reads this configuration file and silently instructions the firmware to boot your choice of operating systems.

Comment: You could also configure rEFInd to not be silent. You can set a delay where rEFInd would  display a menu when you boot/reboot. Here you can also change your choice. If no choice is made, then rEFInd would, after a delay, boot the current default. With this configuration, the AppleScript application would not be necessary.

Comment: I could help with the configuration, but you would have to at least post the output from diskutil list.

Comment: The EFI partition is normally there and normally invisible to the Finder and Disk Utility. Operating systems such as Windows and Linux use the EFI partition to store boot code. MacOS does not use the EFI partition to store boot code, but requires an EFI partition for reasons which have never been fully spelled out. The rEFInd boot manager  normally resides entirely in an EFI partition, although this is not a requirement when installing on intel Mac computers. The EFI partition is FAT32 formatted and is usually 200 to 400 MB in size.

Comment: You say "You could also configure rEFInd to not be silent. You can set a delay where rEFInd would display a menu when you boot/reboot."  If I do this, will that menu include the recovery partition(s), and bootable external media (such as thumb drive or DVD) ?

Comment: The rEFInd Boot Manager can be configured to include the recovery partitions. However, this is a binary flag. In other words, you can display either all recovery partitions or no recovery partitions. You can configure rEFInd to scan and display external bootable media. However, some external media may not be found when rEFInd scans. Therefore,  a manual refresh of rEFInd may be required before the external media is displayed. This can be avoided, if you manually configure rEFInd to display known external media.

Comment: Ok, I managed to install rEFind (had to boot into recovery mode because of SIP). I didn't edit the config file, and it seemed to come right up when I restarted. Seems to show recovery partitions as well as a bootable USB I'd plugged in. I believe that's right - even though I didn't edit the config at all.  Looks like default (from the "sample" config file) is to look for external boot loaders, and also to look for recovery parititions.   Does that sound right ?  If so, then I'm good to go. –

Comment: There are lots of reasons to edit the rEFInd configuration file. However, if the default works for you, then don't.

Comment: BTW, how do I disable rEFind, if I want to use Apple's startup manager ?

Comment: Using the Mac startup manager to set a new default to boot will disable rEFInd. You set a new default in the Mac startup manager by holding down the control key while making a selection to boot. I am not sure if your Mac is new enough to have this control key feature. If not, then you can also disable rEFInd from the Startup Disk pane of macOS System Preferences.

Comment: Mine will use the option key to get to the startup manager.   I do not see any reference to rEFInd in the Startup Disk pane of macOS System Preferences.

Comment: All Intel Macs use the option key to get the Mac Startup Manager. Not all allow the use of the control key to select the default. You did not install rEFInd to appear in the Startup Disk pane of the macOS System Preferences. If you did so, then you would ***not*** be able to select rEFInd from this pane.

Comment: Sorry to keep having to ask and I appreciate your support. I have now installed the new graphics card (Sapphire PULSE Radeon RX 580) and now when I power up the system, I see nothing until the machine is fully booted up (login screen appears). Do I need to change something in the rEFInd config file ?   Perhaps, make it so rEFInd appears in SystemPrefs->StartupDisk and make it the default by selecting there and never changing it ?

Comment: To get rEFInd to appear in SystemPrefs->StartupDisk, thinking it's not the .conf file, but rather done at install time ("FixingMacintosh Boot Problems" at https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html).  This page also looks helpful: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html Still not quite seeing the best path though.

Comment: The [`refind-install`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/refind-install.html) option is `--ownhfs`. If you install rEFInd to appear in the Startup Disk pane of System Preferences, then you will ***not*** be able to select rEFInd as the default to use to startup your computer. You will be able to select rEFInd as the default from the Mac Startup Manager, if the control key can be used while making a selection. In this case, I would recommend the `--usedefault` option when installing.

Comment: I verified I can use the control key to change default in Startup Manager.   But rEFInd does not appear in Startup Manager.  So I need to reinstall using --usedefault ?  I'm unclear what the argument to --usedefault ought to be.   I'm also unclear how to reinstall.  Do I need to uninstall first ?

Comment: I've started a new question "using rEFInd to get around ..."; hopefully this has helped me to focus my thoughts and we can arrive at a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party.
But maybe this can help someone.
I had the same dilemma a while back on my CMP 5,1. My solution was to Install Sierra ( which runs all the old El Capitan stuff. Install an ultra-stripped High Sierra and Mojave( my main OS), which is on NVM PCI, and the other two OSs on a partitioned internal SSD.

1. Sierra sees High Sierra
   (internal partitioned SSD OS Extended (Journaled)
2. High Sierra sees Mojave (on NVM PCI SSD) APFS

So Apple's start-up disc works, just using High Sierra as the middleman. No need for a boot screen. If you can spare 22 GB for High Sierra this might help.
My challenge now is doing all this on an early 2008 Mac via Dosdudes, patcher any advice on the this would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, but the whole question became moot when I realized that High Sierra would not work properly with the new Radeon GPU.   So I'd literally have to swap out graphics cards when changing my boot between Mojave and Sierra or High Sierra.   Also realized my Photoshop installation would not work under Mojave - have to move to one of the subscription periodic fee versions.   So I decided to keep the Mac Pro at High Sierra, and upgrade my much newer laptop to the latest OS, in order to be able to run Turbotax and such.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.